# anomaly detection algorithm problem

Tags: algorithms

I've been trying to determine how to detect point-anomalies given window-anomalies.

In more detail, I know for each 30-day window whether it contains an anomaly. For example, window 1 starts at 1/1/2009, window 2 at 1/2/2009, and so on.

Now I'm trying to use this knowledge to determine which dates these anomalies lie. If I have an anomaly on dates 1/5/2009 to 1/8/2009, my window will raise a signal for windows from a window with a last day of 1/8/2009 to a window starting on 1/5/2009.

I just don't see how I can find the exact intervals where there are anomalies using windows. Is there an approximation method that anyone can come up with that could at least estimate where exactly anomalies are? Feel free to include some code in Python if you'd like.

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose you have at least one anomaly in every 10 days, then you have no info that you could use to pinpoint on which days these anomalies did happen.